# Getting just the date from a bit of text and a date

Tags: sql, date, text

How do I get just the date from a field which is labelled as for example "2015/16 Text" when I just want the date from it?

Comment: what language, what have you tried so far, what format do you need it to be???

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date from a string using the `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(StringColumn, '%Y/%m') FROM table
```

The `%m` and `%Y` are date placeholders. In the resource section of my answer you can find out more about these and which to use in your case.

#### Resource

Visit [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) page for more information